# icon doesnt shows up in the implementation but showing in demo

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

- I am trying to add the delete icon end of my chip.
- its working fine in the material ui demo.
- but its not working in my code.
- I debugged but still I am not able to find the issue. Icon shows up due to this line deleteIcon={}
- I tried changing the button tag to chip tag will that be a problem
- providing my code snippet below

**Not working** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cng5am?file=demo.js

**working demo** https://codesandbox.io/s/qvyvxq7zy6

```
import DoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Done';


        <Chip
          style={{ display: this.state.display ? "" : "none" }}
          label={this.state.chipName}
          onDelete={this.handleDelete}
          color="primary"
          deleteIcon={<DoneIcon />}

        />
        <chip
          style={{ display: this.state.display ? "none" : "" }}
          // aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'simple-menu' : undefined}
          // aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={this.handleClickOpen}
          color="primary"
          deleteIcon={<DoneIcon />}
        >
          Open Menu
        </chip>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D, it doesn't seem practical to include an entire React app here. Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: There are a number of console errors in your non-working demo. Have you investigated those?

Comment: @isherwood - I tried changing the button tag to chip tag will that be a problem

Comment: According to the error, you spelled it incorrectly.

Comment: @isherwood hey I update dthe code but still I dont see the done icon :( can you please update in stackblitz

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the prop `onDelete={() => {}}`. Check the following example:

```
<Chip
      style={{ display: this.state.display ? "" : "none" }}
      label={this.state.chipName}
      onDelete={this.handleDelete}
      color="primary"
      deleteIcon={<DoneIcon />}
      onDelete={() => {}}
/>
```